# Date format not working, shows different date

Tags: datetime, twig

I currently am working on a project, where I have to render events and I am stuck with the date format.

My variable `{{ event.start }}` renders this date in the website: `2021-08-27T00:00:00+02:00[Europe/Vienna]`

When I want to return this date with the right format like that

`{{ event.start|date("d.m.Y") }}`

it shows this date, which is not true: `31.07.2021` (it should be  `27.08.2021`)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does `dump(event.start)` print ? (in Twig template)

Comment: it prints `string(25) "2021-08-18T00:00:00+02:00"`